# Concatenate Text in multiple rows/ columns into a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need help to concatenate values in different columns and rows which has same ID.

```
T_ID    S_ID    S_ID_2
CHG123  0.1       1
CHG123  0.2       2
CHG124  0.1       1
CHG124  0.2       2
CHG124  0.3       3

=======Table====
CREATE TABLE TEST (
T_ID nvarchar(20),
S_ID decimal(1,1),
S_ID_2 int
)

INSERT INTO TEST (T_ID,S_ID, S_ID_2) VALUES 
('CHG123',0.1,1),
('CHG123',0.2,2),
('CHG124',0.1,1),
('CHG124',0.2,2),
('CHG124',0.3,3)
```

How can I convert values in S_ID and S_ID_2 in one string for same T_ID's without grouping.

Trying to achieve something as below(OUTPUT):

```
T_ID    S_ID    S_ID_2          OUTPUT
CHG123  0.1       1             0.1, 0.2, 1, 2
CHG123  0.2       2             0.1, 0.2, 1, 2
CHG124  0.1       1             0.1, 0.2, 1, 2, 3
CHG124  0.2       2             0.1, 0.2, 1, 2, 3
CHG124  0.3       3             0.1, 0.2, 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: does the order of output matter to you? like 0.1,0.2 links with 1 and 2 for CHG123

Comment: @DaleK - I'm fairly new to SQL. Have started using SQL lately..couldn't come up with ideas on how to tackle this.

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph Yes, the concatenation should be sorted in ascending. It should be possible right?

Comment: What's ur SQL server version

Comment: I'm using SQL2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use STRING_AGG for achieving the result.

I am using two CTEs, as I cannot apply single GROUP BY with multiple STRING_AGG, where STRING_AGG have different ORDER BY clause. [Reference](https://sqlxpertise.com/2017/10/05/string_agg-concatenate-values-in-rows-with-separator/)

```sql
;WITH CTE_S_ID_G AS
(
  SELECT T_ID
 , STRING_Agg(S_ID,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY S_ID) AS SID_G
 FROM TEST
 GROUP BY T_ID
), CTE_S_ID_2_G AS
(
  SELECT T_ID
  , STRING_Agg(S_ID_2,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY S_ID_2) AS SID_2_G
 FROM TEST
 GROUP BY T_ID
)
SELECT T.T_ID, T.S_ID, T.S_ID_2, CONCAT(sg.SID_G, ',', S2G.SID_2_G) AS OUTPUT
FROM TEST AS T
INNER JOIN 
CTE_S_ID_G AS SG
ON T.T_ID = SG.T_ID
INNER JOIN 
CTE_S_ID_2_G AS S2G
ON T.T_ID = S2G.T_ID;
```

**Resultset**

```
+--------+------+--------+-------------------+
|  T_ID  | S_ID | S_ID_2 |      OUTPUT       |
+--------+------+--------+-------------------+
| CHG123 |  0.1 |      1 |       0.1,0.2,1,2 |
| CHG123 |  0.2 |      2 |       0.1,0.2,1,2 |
| CHG124 |  0.1 |      1 | 0.1,0.2,0.3,1,2,3 |
| CHG124 |  0.2 |      2 | 0.1,0.2,0.3,1,2,3 |
| CHG124 |  0.3 |      3 | 0.1,0.2,0.3,1,2,3 |
+--------+------+--------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, Venkat!!! 
I just need to figure out a way now to arrange data in VAL in 0.1, 0.2, 1, 2 order. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Praveen, I have updated the answer with proper ORDER BY.